# Ruby Application Built Locally, How do I Put it on to a Website?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a frustrating time with Ruby. I've been working on developing a program that randomly generates a string from two arrays, which I'm all fine and dandy on that front. I'm fluent in the language. The problem I am having is with putting it online. I've been trying to figure out rails with no luck running my piece of software. Anyone able to help me along the way here? I'm unsure how to get this thing into a website for launch

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: @Tetsudou Theres not much to it. There are two arrays, and the program prints out a string by printing a random value from each array. It is saved as a .rb file, and Im just wondering how I put it on to a web server and have a website run it. Do I use rails?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have. Also, on the website, think about the experience you want to have - do you want the user to provide the data for the two arrays? Or do you precreate the arrays and have user click a button on the web page, which then shows the generated string on the page? When you say 'no luck with rails' what did you try? What error did you get? Describe what you want in the web app and also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Show us what you've done to integrate your code into your new rails project. Tell us what tutorials you've read, or google research you've done to learn about how to get it working... etc. ie please show us the effort that you've made... and we can suggest ways to help you improve that doesn't duplicate the effort you've already gone to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Rails is overkill for this. If you only plan on having very simple actions, Sinatra might be better for you. http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

After creating a simple API in Sinatra, you can then serve static assets (HTML, JS, CSS) where you can then use simple AJAX calls to hit your Sinatra backend.

You can get a Heroku account for free to host your application. Hosting a Sinatra application on Heroku should be pretty easy: http://blog.kuntz.co/2014/03/15/deploying-a-sinatra-app-to-heroku.html

Comment: The problem is that later, This is going to be expanded into needing things like the ability to save and rate combinations, log in, etc. for which I'll need to be using a database, and the capabilities that Rails can perform. My biggest confusion is where the code needs to go  for me to call or render it into a .erb file

Comment: I see. Well, it all depends. If these things are going to be stored in a database, then there will need to be a model representing the combinations. This code would either go in that model, or probably more likely from what I can tell, in a module that that model would then use.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get a stronger understanding of Rails. This is what I recommend to everyone who is trying to learn Rails: https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: Okay, so I can put the code into a module, or right into a model and have the controller pull the code and spit out the string?

Comment: And thank you! I'm definitely going to take a read

Comment: Essentially. It sounds like you would want to have a `Generator` module, which a model would then use. That model would be the data representation of those combinations. You would then have a controller that takes requests from the client, parameters included. The controller would instantiate the model and do some data manipulations if necessary. Finally, the controller responds to the request, and your client gets back what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options when it comes to deploying your web app.
A lot will depend on the scale of the application, budget and preference.

You will have mainly 2 main options.

1. Ready to use options
   Ex. [heroku](http://heroku.com), [enginyard](https://www.engineyard.com/)
2. Do it yourself options
   Normal servers Ex. [Digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)

After you make this decision you will find it way easier to deploy your app.

In case of heroku(its free I recommend it for start) reference [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

If you do it on your own you will have to deiced which server will you use
Nginx, apache or others

Check out [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)